# Sneaky Inject variable in class constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection

I'm using typescript for test automation and I have a tons of classes like this:

```
class Something {
//properties
constructor(page:Page){}
//methods
}
```

```js
class Account {
//properties
constructor(page:Page, accountNumber: string){}
//methods
}
```

```js
class Navigation {
//properties
constructor(page:Page, navigation: NavigationStrategy){}
//methods
}
```

The same `page:Page` object I should pass to all my constructors
e.g

```
it("some test" async => {
const page = await browser.newPage();
const searchPage = new SearchPage(page);
const account = new Account(page, "2135");
const navigation = new Navigation(page, new LHSNavigation(page));
})
```

How can I automaticaly inject this `page` object to all constructors?
For example I want to get next result:

```
it("some test" async => {
const page = await browser.newPage();
const pageProvider = new PageProvider(page)
const searchPage = pageProvider.create(SearchPage);
// OR
const account = pageProvider.create(Account)("2135");

// OR maybe
const navigation = pageProvider.create(Navigation, LHSNavigation);
})
//Or maybe without page provider
const navigation = Navigation(LHSNavigation);
```

And all types should be resolved in compile time

Comment: Are we assuming that each constructor always takes `Page` as the first parameter?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you